# PHP check that string has 2 numbers, 8 chars and 1 capital

Tags: php, regex, character, uppercase, digits

I found lots of php regex and other options to determine string length, and if it contains one letter or one number, but how do I determine if a string has 2 numbers in it?

I am trying to validate a password that

- Must have exactly 8 characters
- One of them must be an Uppercase letter
- 2 of them must be numbers

Is there a one line regex solution for this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to limit the length of a password to 8 characters? Hope you're not working for a bank...

Comment: FYI you are my hero. Awesome solution.

Comment: Maybe you could try to convince your client to lift that restriction? What use is a password that any household PC can crack in a few hours by brute force?

Answer (score 7):

```
if (preg_match(
    '/^            # Start of string
    (?=.*\p{Lu})   # at least one uppercase letter
    (?=.*\d.*\d)   # at least two digits
    .{8}           # exactly 8 characters
    $              # End of string
    /xu',     
    $subject)) {
    # Successful match
```

`(?=...)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It checks if a certain regex can be matched at the current position, but doesn't actually consume any part of the string, so you can just place several of those in a row.

Comment: I recommend proof reading your answer before sending it :P Couldn't read it through once without being prompted to reload it for your every subsequent edits

Comment: @Codemonkey: Yeah, sorry. First I misplaced one of the comments, and only then I realized that he was asking for *exactly*  8 characters. Which is a horrible idea for a password restriction...

Comment: It is, it says so in the question :-)

Comment: +1 Brilliant solution with the lookaheads. Didn't know they could be used like this. I was writing an answer using three separate queries to do the validation, but I like this much better. Can you explain what the `\p` and `{Lu}` parts do, as well as the `u` modifier?

Comment: @billwilliams: if the answer worked (and it looks like it did), please accept it by clicking the green check mark :-)